# How to stop tabs when they have empty elements?

Tags: javascript

How to make the tabs stop when there are empty fields that prevent the advance of the tabs
Once the fields that by the way have required are filled in, but it doesn't work for me, the tabs don't stop
If I have empty fields in step 1, prevent it from being able to give next and get to step 2
If I have in step 2, even if it is an empty input, it will prevent me from reaching step 3
I don't know how to do what I'm asking
On the same page I have several sections. called one, two and three
prevent the advance of the next button when there are empty fields
the button should be disabled once all the fields are filled enable it and do the same in tab 2 that is disabled and when all the fields are filled enable it to go to section 3

summary of what to do
1- show the message: "the field is required" in each input

2- the next button must be disabled

3- the button must be activated when the last input is finished writing (I think it is the onblur event)

```js
class TabbedContent {
          constructor() {
            this.tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".nav li");
            this.sections = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
            this.nextButton = document.querySelector("#nextBtn");
            this.prevButton = document.querySelector("#prevBtn");
            this.current = 0;
          }
    
          toggleTabs() {
            this.tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
              tab.classList.remove('active');
            });
            this.tabs[this.current].classList.add("active");
          }
    
          toggleSections() {
            this.sections.forEach(function(section) {
              section.classList.remove('active');
            });
            this.sections[this.current].classList.add("active");
          }
    
          togglePrev() {
            const method = this.current == 0 ? 'add' : 'remove';
            this.prevButton.classList[method]("disable");
          }
    
          toggleNext() {
            const method = this.current == this.tabs.length - 1 ? 'add' : 'remove';
            this.nextButton.classList[method]("disable");
          }
    
          goNext() {
            if (this.current < this.tabs.length - 1) {
              this.current++
            }
            this.toggleTabs();
            this.toggleSections();
            this.toggleNext();
            this.togglePrev();
          }
    
          goPrev() {
            if (this.current > 0) {
              this.current--
            }
            this.toggleTabs();
            this.toggleSections();
            this.toggleNext();
            this.togglePrev();
          }
    
        }
    
        const tabbedContent = new TabbedContent();
```

```css
.container {
          max-width: 600px;
          margin: 0 auto;
          text-align: center;
        }
    
        .section {
          display: none;
        }
    
        .section.active {
          display: block;
        }
    
        ul {
          list-style: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
        }
    
        ul li {
          background: #ccc;
          padding: 10px 15px;
          margin-left: 6px;
          border-radius: 50%;
          cursor: pointer;
          opacity: .5;
        }
    
        ul li.active {
          opacity: 1 !important;
        }
    
        .next,
        .previous {
          padding: 15px 10px;
          border-radius: 6px;
          background: deepskyblue;
          color: white;
          border: 0;
          outline: none;
          cursor: pointer;
          width: 100px;
        }
    
        .next.disable,
        .previous.disable {
          cursor: none;
          opacity: .5;
        }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active">1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
          </ul>
    
    
          <section class="section section-one active">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
   minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
   minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">

<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
   minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">

<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
   minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">

          </section>
          <section class="section section-two">
         <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
   minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
   minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">

          </section>
          <section class="section section-three">
            <h2>section 3</h2>
          </section>
    
    
          <button class="previous disable" id="prevBtn" onclick="tabbedContent.goPrev()">Previous</button>
          <button class="next" id="nextBtn" onclick="tabbedContent.goNext()">Next</button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more method to `TabbedContent` class which gonna tell you whether you should go next or not as:

[`CODESANDBOX`](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-margulis-dg4dd7?file=/main.js)

```
  isAllFieldsFilled() {
    const current = this.current;
    const allInputs = [...this.sections];
    const currentSection = allInputs?.[current];
    let shouldGoNext = true;
    if (currentSection) {
      const allInputs = currentSection.querySelectorAll("input");
      for (let input of allInputs) {
        const value = input.value;
        if (!value) return false;
      }
    }
    return shouldGoNext;
  }
```

and you have to use it in `goNext` method as:

```
  goNext() {
    if (this.isAllFieldsFilled()) {
      if (this.current < this.tabs.length - 1) {
        this.current++;
      }
      this.toggleTabs();
      this.toggleSections();
      this.toggleNext();
      this.togglePrev();
    }
  }
```

Comment: It is close to what is required, by my mistake, it does not show "the field is required"
2 the next button is not disabled or activated as you stop writing, thanks in advance